# Load error in Rspec and full Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to migrate Rails app to use Rails engines. My plan is to not use mountable engines for now and migrate to them later.

Folders structure looks like this:

```
config
engines
  common
    app
      models
    lib
      common
        namespaced_lib
  web
    app
      controllers
      helpers
      views
    config
features
lib
public
script
spec
vendor
```

Engines are defined like this:

```
module Common
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    engine_dir = File.expand_path('../..', File.dirname(__FILE__))
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[engine_dir + '/app/models/**/']
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[engine_dir + '/lib/**/']
  end
end

module Web
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
  end
end
```

There is a `Data` class in `lib/common/namespaced_lib` folder of Common engine. In code it is referenced only as `NamespacedLib::Data` and never as `Data`.

```
module NamespacedLib
  class Data
  end
end
```

And there is a DataController (inside of engines/web/app/controllers):

```
class DataController < ApplicationController
end
```

When I run rspec I get following error. This error never happened before I moved to engines.

```
rspec
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /engines/common/lib/common/namespaced_lib/data.rb to define Data (LoadError)
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:260:in `safe_constantize'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `safe_constantize'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:152:in `_default_wrap_model'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in `_set_wrapper_defaults'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:133:in `inherited'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.19/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from /engines/web/app/controllers/data_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:444:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:443:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:441:in `eager_load!'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `eager_load!'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /spec/spec_helper.rb:46:in `require'
    from /spec/spec_helper.rb:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /spec/spec_helper.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from /spec/controllers/approvals_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /spec/controllers/approvals_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
```

I tried to rename `DataController` to `DataRenamedController` and the error went away. So it looks like Rails or Rspec tries to auto-load `Data` class when it sees `DataController`. Is there a way to disable this?